# Can I automatically forward transactions from a given address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, ethereum-wallet-dapp

The challenge is to provably promise to transfer a transaction from address X to address Y. Basically, I need to be able to convince Y that if I get the money from X - it's going straight to Y. X is some smart contract that will eventually send me tokens - and I'd like to sell this potential future transfer, sort of like a derivative contract. Is this viable?
It's going to be tokens, in case it makes a difference.

If I run a smart contract with address A - I guess it won't be difficult to make it so that any balance received from X to A will go directly to Y. However, X is also a smart contract - can they refuse to do business with smart contracts and only accept money from (and send to) only wallet addresses?

If X can do that (ban smart contracts) - we can make the challenge extra interesting; can I do the same with my own address? AFAIU, a transaction cannot go out from my address without my intervention as signing it needs my private key. I could sign it ahead of time and promise to broadcast it later - but still, can I make the transaction get triggered when the balance arrives from X?

Comment: Ethereum account is not an email account, so no "forwards" for EOAs. As for contracts, you can implement any logic you want, and in that case the User's address must be provided as contract's input.

Comment: "the User's address must be provided as contract's input" - the question is, can I provide my own address so that the contract will later transfer from it? Doesn't it need my private key to do that?
Additionally, can the smart contract be triggered by a transaction to my account?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your idea correctly.

You'd like to have a contract (addr `X`) which has a custom filter for receiving transactions. In case if transactions coming from specific address (addr `A`) values automatically forwarding to (addr `Y`).

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Tranfer { // address X
    
    event Forward(address to);
    
    address private transferTo = 0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2; // address Y
    address private transferFrom = 0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c; // address A
    
    receive() external payable {
        if (msg.sender == transferFrom) {
            emit Forward(msg.sender);
            payable(transferTo).transfer(msg.value);
        }
    }
}
```

In general you need to modify the `receive()`

Comment: Thanks, this solves the easier version of the problem - doing it form a smart contract address.

Comment: Is the automatic forwarding of any incoming transaction itself gas-free for the recipient/contract owner?